# how can I use thymeleaf iteration(loop) in table?

Tags: html, frontend, thymeleaf

```
<table>
        <tr th:each="product : ${data}">
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" name="productCode" th:value="${product.productCode}" th:text="${product.productName}" />
            </td>
        </tr>
</table>
```

If there are 100 products,
Currently, each product is aligned vertically one per line.

If I want to printing 5 products per line, and move to the next line, how can I use 'iterator'?

tried below code, but failed

Answer (score 0):

For this purpose, there is such a thing as iterStat. Is a mechanism useful for keeping track of the state of your iteration: a state variable.
This shows how you can output 5 items and then move to a new line.

```
    <table>
    <tr th:each="product, iterStat : ${data}">
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" name="productCode" th:value="${product.productCode}" th:text="${product.productName}" />
        </td>
        <th:block th:if="${iterStat.count % 5 == 4 and !iterStat.last}">
            </tr><tr>
        </th:block>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: thanks, But there were some errors..
Element th:block is not closed
Element table is not closed

Comment: Yes sorry it was in my reply, but the formatting of the code was not affected, and it was thrown out for some reason.